# or-pattern on datatype. Partial as?

Tags: ocaml

Trying to cobble together a lambda calculus interpreter as a noob project and I have come upon a syntax problem I cannot quite figure out.

Problem being that two constructors of a type behaves the same in some respects and I would like to avoid code duplication. See code below.

```
type term =
  | Lam of string * term * term
  | Pi of string * term * term

let rec subst x t s = match s with
  | Lam (y,r,q) | Pi (y,r,q) ->
    if x = y then LAMORPI (y, subst x t r, q)
    else [...]
```

What I think are called or-patterns seemed like a good fit but I cannot get it to work. Figured perhaps that is what as is for, but I cannot seem to partially as something, which is what I had in mind for LAMORPI to be doing. This case seems like it would have a neat or commonly used idiomatic solution but my google-fu is not strong enough.

What is a usual or otherwise possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use or-pattern in expressions. (And this potential feature raises some issues: see http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/pattern-synonyms-as-expressions for a discussion)

One possibility is to refactor your type to expose the fact that the two constructors only differ by a tag:

```ml
type kind = Lam | Pi
type term =
  | LamPi of tag * string * term * term
  | ...

let rec subst x t s = match s with
  | LamPi (tag,y,r,q) ->
    if x = y then LamPi (tag, y, subst x t r, q)
    else ...
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks kindly for entertaining a troubled noob, and for the interesting read besides.